# ngOnInit doesn't run again when navigating back to the component?

Tags: angular

I have two Angular 6 components. In one of the components, I have a simple `div` that displays a total value, such as this:

```
<div>{{ totalDailyCalories }}</div>
```

And the `.ts` (pseudo code):

```
export class TotalDailyCalories {
  public totalDailyCalories: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    // pseudo code - fetchTotalDailyCalories sends an http req to the 
    // backend and retrieves the total amount of calories
    this.totalDailyCalories = this.fetchTotalDailyCalories
  }
}
```

Then, if I navigate to another component where I can edit the total number of calories, then navigate back to my `totalDailyCalories` component, the value is still the old one. I thought that `ngOnInit` will run again after navigating back to the `TotalDailyCalories`, but the `fetchTotalDailyCalories` is not being fired at all. It only fires once when I navigate to the `totalDailyCalories` component for the first time.

How can I update the `totalDailyCalories` to the latest value? Or in other words, how can I re-run the `fetchTotalDailyCalories` from my `totalDailyCalories` component?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the `fetchTotalDailyCalories` that's not working correctly? Try some simple logging (console.log) to double check that `ngOnInit()` is running each time. As long as the component is destroyed when navigating away, it will be recreated (and therefore re-initialised) when re-navigated to

Comment: Have a look to https://medium.com/engineering-on-the-incline/reloading-current-route-on-click-angular-5-1a1bfc740ab2

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`implements OnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) on the class and import it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log("component initialized");
  }

}
```